# Spring Boot Format Json encoded Timstamp

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rabbit

From RabbitMQ getting below JSON

```
{"PlateNo":"A125","DeviceId":"D152","Time":"/Date(1584260162000)/","Latitude":25.59483611111111,"Longitude":56.30596666666667,"Address":"Dibba, Fujairah, UAE","GPSSpeed":0,"IsValid":false}
```

After `ObjectMapper`,

How to format the `Time` field in the spring boot?

Answer (score 1):

on date field use below annotation :-

```
@JsonFormat(
  shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", locale = "en_GB")
```

and use below dependency :-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: get below error:
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "/Date(1584260162000)/": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '/Date(1584260162000)/' could not be parsed at index 0